# Postgres JSON function with group by

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

**Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE profit_center
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  site_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT profit_center_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT profit_center_name_site_id_key UNIQUE (name, site_id)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04630/4

**Query which I have tried :**

```
select site_id,json_build_object(name,id) as jsn from profit_center;
```

I want to group by all the `jsn` values by `site_id`. Expected result in single row :

```
{
    "1": {
        "Darshan": "1",
        "ABC": 2
    },
    "2": {
        "XYZ": 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks bad, but [returns your expected result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04630/13):

```
with r as (select concat('"',site_id,'": ',concat('{',string_agg(concat('"',name,'": ',id),','),'}')::json) from profit_center group by site_id)
select concat('{',string_agg(concat,','),'}')::json from r;
```

Comment: Three json generated. It should be only two since two site id available.